# how to crop an image (frame) within canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have multiple frames in one single image. How do I paint the crop of an image within the canvas?

Party pooper is that the canvas is stretched out and responsive via CSS. Example:

[image]

Say, every frame is 100x100px and I want to paint frame "5". So I have to paint frame following position: x100, y200, width100, height 100

My code looks something like this:

```
this.ctx = this.canvas.get(0).getContext("2d");
this.ctx.drawImage(this.image, - this.imageWidth * x, - this.imageHeight * y, this.image.width, this.image.height);
```

All values come out correct in my console but the result is jack shit. Did I interpret drawImage wrong?

Comment: Does this have to be a canvas? I don't see a reason, you are not drawing. Why not use CSS3 sprites? They were made for this.

Comment: two reasons: The function is tied to a scroll, and I can not resize my sprite. within the responsive container properly.

Comment: You certainly could still use CSS sprites, by manipulating the `backgroundPosition` relative to the responsive container`s size.

Comment: Forgot to articulate that, `backgroundPosition` also takes percentage values....

Answer (score 0):

why are you using negative values ?

for the "5", you should use :

```
this.ctx.drawImage(this.image, 100, 100);
```

or if your sprite hasn't the right size :

```
this.ctx.drawImage(this.image, 100, 100, 100, 100);
```

doc for drawImage :
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage